# Talend date format tparse date

Tags: talend

Here below my requirement
empno,empname,sal,HRA,deptno,joindate
100,MAHeSH,14500,120,10,12-08-2016
101,Naresh,20000,110,20,12-12-2016
102,Rahul,15000,125,30,15-12-2015
103,Abdul,61000,135,30,10-06-2017
As they have given interview question as like need to fetch 12-12-2016 and below data.
so i have tried to below date function for fetch the data,but while I am trying to fetch I am getting an error as like

--**TalendDate.compareDate(row6.joindate,TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yyyy","12-12-2016"))==0
--***Cannot convert to boolen to date

Plz help me on this isse

Comment: This question lacks a clear structure, formatting and more background info.

Comment: What is the type of your "row6.joindate" column ?

Comment: @ThéoCapdet in date format

Answer (score -1):

TalendDate.compareDate(row6.joindate,TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yyyy","12-08-2016"))<=0 && TalendDate.compareDate(row6.joindate,TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yyyy","15-15-2015"))>=0